# Filtering an NSArray of NSDictionaries using multiple criteria

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray, nspredicate

I am filter my an array with the following code

```
NSArray *_filteredArray = [self.allData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    NSDictionary *_dataRow = (NSDictionary *)evaluatedObject;
    return ([[[_dataRow valueForKey:@"name"] lowercaseString]  rangeOfString:[self.searchBar.text lowercaseString]].location != NSNotFound);
}]];
```

As you can see in the snippet I only match `@"name"`; how can I check a second parameter (for example `@"city"`) to be matched with my filter?

I tried `allKeys` and `allValues`, but neither worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
NSArray *_filteredArray = [self.allData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
NSDictionary *_dataRow = (NSDictionary *)evaluatedObject;
return ([[[_dataRow valueForKey:@"name"] lowercaseString]  rangeOfString:[self.searchBar.text lowercaseString]].location != NSNotFound) || ([[[_dataRow valueForKey:@"surname"] lowercaseString]  rangeOfString:[self.searchBar.text lowercaseString]].location != NSNotFound);
}]];
```

Comment: You are absolutely awesome. Thank you very much.

Comment: Nice to help you. Add as many OR (||) statements you like of course. You can accept and vote the answer if it helped you :-)